# How to access SESSION of loggedInUser outside CakePHP 2.x

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I need to know if a user is logged in and need to access at his infos outside CakePHP but on the same domain.

I've tried the following code

```
session_start();
session_name('CAKEPHP');
if(isset($_COOKIE['CAKEPHP'])){
  session_id($_COOKIE['CAKEPHP']);
  echo "isset<br/>";
  var_dump($_SESSION);
}
echo "user :".$_SESSION['userCakeUser']['email'];
```

I have the follwing output :

```
isset

array(1) {

 ["userCakeUser"]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (7)
   { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(12) "loggedInUser" 
    ["email"]=> string(17)  "a@a.net"<
    ["hash_pw"]=> string(65) "dsfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfddsfsdfsdfsdf" 
    ["user_id"]=> int(4) ["title"]=> string(10) "New Member"   
    ["displayname"]=> string(5) "Toto"
    ["username"]=> string(5) "Toto"
  }
}
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array on line 15
```

Please can you tell me how do I access the email for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Inigo Flores,

It is better, but I had the following error :

> Notice: main(): The script tried to execute a method or access a property of an incomplete object. Please ensure that the class definition "loggedInUser" of the object you are trying to operate on was loaded *before* unserialize() gets called or provide a __autoload() function to load the class definition on line 16`

So I have Included this class :

`include("path_to_cake_php/models/class.user.php" )`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is giving you enough information about what is wrong:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type __PHP_Incomplete_Class as array on line 15
```

It's an object what you are dealing with. Try:

```
echo "user :".$_SESSION['userCakeUser']->email;
```